# Google Big Query, convert legacy sql to standard sql

Tags: regex, google-bigquery, legacy-sql

I'm trying to convert a `LegacySql` Query to `StandardSQL`

```
SELECT  * FROM 
TABLE_QUERY([prod-chap_out],'REGEXP_MATCH(table_id, r"OUT\d+$")')
```

This query works fine in Legacy SQL, however it can't be converted to a json response when used in API's. I would rather serialize this into json than have to work with a bunch of data tables and converting values.

How can this be converted to standardSQL?

I've tried

```
REGEXP_CONTAINS(table_id, r"OUT\d+$"))
```

but I get the error \d is an illegal character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the wildcard `*` in your `FROM` and the resulting pseudo column `_table_suffix` in your `WHERE`:

```sql
SELECT
  * 
FROM 
  `<project-id>.<dataset-id>.<table-prefix>*`
WHERE 
  REGEXP_MATCH(_table_suffix, r"OUT\d+$")
```

I'm not entirely sure how you table names look like - here is the official documentation on transitioning to standard SQL: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference#the_table_query_function

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking for.